# /etc/network/interfaces.bak is showing different interface then ifconfig

Tags: networking, network-manager

ifconfig command shows : enp0s3 interface and lo loop back network interface
but when i did

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

it showed empty

```
 #interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
 #Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
 source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

but interface.d showed

```
 #interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
 #Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
 source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

 #the loopback network interface
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 #the primary network interface
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

even if i do

```
ifconfig -a
```

i dont have eth0. is enp0s3 an alias.
I can't really understand why i have eth0 instead of enp0s3 and why interface is empty

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Is it `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/network/interfaces.bak`?

Comment: ubutnu version is 20.04 /etc/network/interfaces is empty but /etc/network/interfaces.bak has eth0 and lo interface

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/network/interfaces.bak` is a backup file where someone has saved an old config.

It is not used by the system. You can safely delete it, if it confuses you.

Comment: then should i just add the interfaces info in the /etc/network/interfaces file ?

Comment: No, that will break things. You shouldn't use this file in Ubuntu excuding some very special cases.